# Is it possible to Store the contents in a Vector but not in a session every time the Servlet is called

Tags: java, servlets

Is it possible to store the contents of a request in either `Vector` or `Arraylist` when client sends some data and keep the content intact in that vector no matter how many times the servlet is called. I do not want to hold the data in the session.

Comment: Is the Vector going to contain unique info for each user? if not, you could store in Application context.

Comment: As Crollster said, Application Context. Or you can use a static variable to hold your data.

Comment: The Vector is going to be like a shopping cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiate the Vector in which you want to store the contents only once then the older data will remain intact. But still it is a good practice to store the data as session attributes.

Look at the following example:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException
 {
Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
 vector.add(request.getParameter("name"));
 }
```

Here everytime you call the GET method a new vector is allocated memory so there is no way you can refer to the old data here. But if you instantiate it only once then the data will be updated not refreshed:

```
 public class "servletName" extends HttpServlet{

   private Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException
     {
     vector.add(request.getParameter("UID"));
     } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm. I edited your answer a little bit.

Comment: Servlet should not have state. It's a pretty bad design. You should keep the vector in somewhere else.

Comment: @Trying I just focused on the specific doubt that the person who posted had. I know the code that I have posted is a bad design.

Comment: You could have achieved the same by different means.

Comment: @Trying As in? Assume Vector was declared somewhere else, is there still any other way to get the desired results? I would really appreciate it if you could tel me. I am always looking for work-arounds and better coding ways.